# Is there any strategy against adaptoids?

Tags: sword-of-the-stars-the-pit

I'm having problem with adaptoids, they're annoying and not always easy to deal with. Even if i manage to kill them fast they still manage to do a lot of damage to my armor and weapons. And sometimes they just jump at me at surprise and kill me.

Is there any strategy to dealing with them, any preemptive i can take against them? Is there any way i could make them show themself from safe distance without destroying the object i might suspect is adaptoid? Can sensor detect adaptoids in the room?

Comment: If your speed is high enough you can kite them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adaptoids are annoying at best and deadly at worst, here are some strategies when dealing with them:

1. Take note of what type of room you're in and the stuff within it. You don't typically see a Medical bay in a Kitchen or Weapon area, do you? It's probably an adaptoid.
2. I usually keep a low damage gun/weapon for finding adaptoids - if I suspect something is an adaptoid, I'll shoot it. Since my weapon is low damage, it doesn't destroy the thing (Med-bay etc.) but it will reveal an adaptoid from far away.
3. Be careful when you interact with things, if you click the button while facing it, and it doesn't activate, it's probably an adaptoid. Sometimes adaptoids are 'sleeping' and don't notice when you're right next to them.
4. Using an item like an engineer's sonar/sensor item will show you enemies on the mini-map - I suspect that it will show adaptoids - but I'll be honest, that's one of the first items I throw away when I need space.

Answer (score 0):

How to preempt / detect / avoid Adaptoids ;

1. When approaching an interactive item, never step up to it directly. Stop 1 square away, then hit **X** to end your turn. Now, with 2 move, step in to the item, and press space to interact. If it's not interactive, it's an adaptoid. Use your second move to move away, and the adaptoid usually won't act.
2. Items such as the Motion Sensor, and Psi powers such as Life Sense, reveal adaptoids on your minimap.
3. The use of a low damage, low penetration weapon could be used to "test" interactive items. If they are adaptoids, they will immediately respond when damaged. A low damage, status effect grenade could also suit this purpose. This does hold the danger you indicated, i.e. that the item could be destroyed in the "testing", as well as possibly being a drain on ammunition, if used on every interactive item.
4. Learn what the symbols above doorways mean. This gives you an indication to what type of room you are entering, and hence what type of interactive items to expect. An unusual item for a particular type of room, such as a medical bay in a kitchen or an armour locker in a medical lab, can be an indicator of an adaptoid.